# UI of Sitecore CMS os available in how many languages to editors?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

while working in sitecore, the UI of it is available in how many languages. For example, the translated string of 'OK' 'Cancel', 'Error' etc kind of messages are present by default, or we need to install separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI is available in English, Danish, German, and Japanese (4), based on the the client translation packs listed on the [Sitecore 8.1 download page](https://dev.sitecore.net/en/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/Sitecore_81/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_81_Update2.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can install a CMS client translation files to run the Sitecore Client in an alternative language, Depend on the version there are some languages available.

For Sitecore 6 and 7 see: [CMS Client Translations](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Resources/Client_Translations/CMS%20Client%20Translations.aspx)

For Installing. In Sitecore Open the Control Panel > Globalization > Import Languages from a File.

For version 8 and higher there are also Client Languages packs available on the newer [dev.sitecore.net](http://dev.sitecore.net/) here too it varies by version which languages there are. usually it takes some time when there is a new version.